# Configure apache 2 using SSL with proxy to gunicorn server in Solaris 11

Tags: python, apache2, ssl-certificate, solaris, gunicorn

I have a python flask application and I am using Gunicorn as the WSGI - Gateway Interface server to the application. I have installed Apache 2.2 web server which captures the user's request and forwards it to Gunicorn through ProxyPass. The whole thing is running on Solaris 11.

I have created a self-signed certificate and placed the .crt and .key file in the apache2 directory.

This is my relative Directory Structure to the relevant files in Apache just to give an idea how it's placed,
1) ../apache2/2.2/conf.d/vhosts.conf
2) ../apache2/2.2/ttpd.conf

Here, I have added "Listen 443" in httpd.conf file and virtualHost tag in vhosts.conf file like mentioned below,

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
SSLSessionCache "....."
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName 127.0.0.1
ServerSignature On
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/2.2/localhost.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "etc/apache2/2.2/localhost.key"
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /https://127.0.1:8002/
ProxyPassReverse /https://127.0.1:8002/
</VirtualHost>
```

When I enable the apache2.2 server it simply gives me this error : caught SIGTERM, shutting down.

Gunicorn configuration looks perfect as I was able to point to my self-signed certificate and https is working all fine when I directly open using "/https://127.0.1:8002/" in the browser, as Gunicorn is configured to run on port:8002.

But I am not able to go to redirect to Gunicorn from Apache. I am not sure if I am missing something. Please help

Thanks in Advance !